# How to select a UV island?

Tags: mesh, uv, workflow, selection-tools

How do you select an entire UV island on a mesh by selecting a piece of the desired island?  Similar to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for selecting all connecting geometry, only selecting all geometry within seams.

I.E. select a vertex within an island.

[image: mesh with seam marked]

And hit some hot-key to extend the selection to the marked seams.

[image: mesh selected]

I use this feature all the time in 3ds Max, so I can unwrap a piece at a time. It would be a huge timesaver to be able to do this in Blender as well.

Comment: That's odd.. The select linked operator has a *limit by seams* option in the redo panel (F6), but it doesn't seem to work? Might be a bug.

Comment: Limit by seams only works in face-select mode (note, Blender should really be changed to report a warning if used in vert/edge mode)

Comment: I mean there should be, as in - We should add one!, Will try resolve these issues (and make some other planned improvements) to select linked in the next week or 2.

Comment: Update, this is now supported in Blender 2.75.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To select an entire island within seam boundaries: In edit mode activate FACE SELECT, hover the mouse over the wanted island, and press L.

Not exactly what you are asking for, but hopefully helpful.

Answer (score 13):

### Update, UV islands in Vert/Edge/Face modes [has been added](https://developer.blender.org/rB3aa4a0e787993ddecaff30f36c502af20250837e)

In the operator options, enable UV as a delimiter to select UV islands:

- Select a vertex/edge/face.
- Press Ctrl+LKey.
- Enable UV option in toolbar.

### Previous answer (Versions 2.74 or older)

Select linked can delimit by seams, but this only works in face-select mode *****:

- Switch to face select mode
- Press LKey over the region, the selection will be restricted to the seams.

If you don't have seams around the UV island, you can automatically create them.

- Image Window, UV -> Seams from Islands

***** - *this is intentional, select-linked traverses only **faces** in face-select mode, and **edges** in vert/edge mode.*