# How do I measure the distance between two UV vertices?

Tags: measurement

I am using Blender version 2.77a. I am attempting to make a paper model of a mesh that has been UV mapped, but not to scale. I need to:

- Measure the distance between any two vertices on a UV map
- Make a duplicate of a UV island

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Can't you blow up the the UV layout and print it at whatever size you need?

Comment: ....or are you wanting to make the papercraft version without having to print out the UV layout?

Comment: What do you mean by "make a duplicate of a UV island", wouldn't Shift+D be sufficient, or I am I not understanding what a UV island is?

Comment: Duplicate an UV island makes no sense. "Geometry" in the UV mapping is dependant on the actual geometry. You can't add anything only in the UV geometry.

Comment: By duplicate a UV island I was wondering if it was possible to copy a UV island without copying geometry(some parts of the model were mapped to the same UV coordinates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is any true way to measure the distance between two vertices in the uv image editor, but there is a fairly simple workaround.

## Finding the (x,y) distance between two points

With your mesh unwrapped and the UV/image editor open, open the properties panel within the editor via <kbd>n</kbd>. At the top there will be what is called "UV vertex". Once you select a vertex it will tell you the coordinates of the vertex.

[image: Selected Vertex]

 Okay, now the hard part. After finding the coordinates of the second vertex use the distance formula, which is:
√ (x<sub>2</sub>−x<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>+(y<sub>2</sub>−y<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> 
 

 This [online distance caculator](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/calculators/distance-formula-calculator.php) should make things easier.

## Duplicating a UV island

*In 3D View* 

First and foremost you must select the desired UV island, like so: 

1. Enter edit mode <kbd>TAB</kbd> 

2. Put select mode on "face" <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> 

3. Hover mouse over the desired UV island and press L. 

4. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> 
      
*In UV/Image Editor*

Whatever you copy and paste in 3-D view should appear in the image editor.

## References

[How to select a UV island?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16184/how-to-select-a-uv-island)

Comment: I'm not sure if calculating the distance in pixels is the right way here, at least calculate it with normalized coordinates so the range will be 0 to 1.00 ;  by default an unwrapped mesh with no image loaded will be mapped on an empty canvas size of 256x256 pixels , once you load an image your calculated distance is off , especially if the image is not square dimension. not to mention the rounding errors between integers and decimals. i may be wrong about this though.