# Select whole object parts after it has already seams?

Tags: modeling, uv, 3d-view

I noticed when working on my objects which consist of multiple smaller parts, that when I already unwrapped them and now want to select some objects with L it will only select the UV island but not the whole object anymore. Is there another operation I have to use now or a button to press to let blender know that I do not want to select UV islands but the whole mesh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Select Linked](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/modeling/curves/selecting.html#select-linked) has options in the Last Operator panel (once it was executed).

Often by default *Seams* option is checked which means selected linked geometry will be limited with the seams added to the mesh:

[image: screenshot-how-selected-linked-uses-seams-to-outwit-all]

This is useful for [selecting only one UV island within the current mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16184/how-to-select-a-uv-island) without picking seams manually.
To disable that uncheck *Seams* and all the linked geometry of the mesh will be selected.